# IntelliJ IDEA rest client JSON response not parsed correctly compared to command line cURL

Tags: json, http, intellij-idea, circleci

The response from the IntelliJ rest client is mangled and isn't parsed as JSON.  The 401 unauthorized code is expected.

```
GET https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/me

# Response
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-route: /api/v1.1/me
Content-Length: 35

## Malformed JSON
{
  :message "You must log in first."}
```

[image: IntelliJ malformed JSON]

However, cURL with the same URL has JSON output:

```
$ curl https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/me
{
  "message" : "You must log in first."
}
```

How do I get JSON from the IntelliJ rest client?

Comment: It seems to be a legit issue, Postman also manages to print the JSON properly. Please submit this to the issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=WI

Comment: Created issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47587?project=WI